# Recline.js tutorial example comes up blank. Perhaps related to Leaflet IE bug?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm working through this simple example of making a map from a dataset using Recline.js :: http://okfnlabs.org/recline/docs/tutorial-views.html

When I duplicate the steps, I get a white screen of death.

My code is hosted here: http://theplaceisnow.aedileworks.com/mappings/recline/TimeToRecline.html

I've checked the links of all the dependencies.

Chrome tells me that there are errors in the Leaflet.js and that the tiles will not load. I haven't found anyone else with the same error, but it's possible it's related to a correction made for an IE bug (although I'm using FF and Chrome): github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/1202

Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated

========================================================

Update :

I tried switching to Leaflet 0.4.4 which did not change the problem.

A friend suggested that the problem might be the body tag.  I moved the body tag to before the script and that allowed Leaflet to run.

Tiles still don't load locally in a browser but when uploaded to a server, the map loads properly.

Comment: Seems to work fine at the link you posted.... what fixed it?

Comment: I moved the body tag to before the script!

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows you are using leaflet 0.7.3 while the tutorial you are quoting uses leaflet 0.4.4.

This should solve your problem.

If you look at [recline](https://github.com/okfn/recline/) project, you can see they added support to leaflet 0.7.3 very recently.

They have not yet updated their website which is hosted on github: https://github.com/okfn/recline/tree/gh-pages

Answer (score 0):

Recline could not detect leaflet. If I disable recline.js and  slickgrid,  it detects any version of leaflet.